# Custom Error mode in Web.Config File

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-config

I have deployed my application on server and Now I am getting this error:

To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

~~~ I have defined custom error pages for my applicatio.

Comment: Which is your **final** ***config*** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically there is one of three causes, but we would have to see a web.config to get detail.

1. You have an improper ASP.NET version selected in IIS so it cannnot get to your settings
2. You have a malformed item in your web.config so the structure isn't correct
3. Your custom errors section is commented out.....

Comment: Thanks Mitchel,

But the same solution is working on my local, also When I am making it "Off" then I am 
getting this error message for this line

<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

I am using chart control in my application, is this because of IIS version on server ??

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - Are you sure .Net 3.5 is installed on the server?

Comment: I am not sure, I have to ask my hosting provider. If this might be the cause then please suggest me the way forward.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - That is the only way, check with your hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks NIck, I'll get back to this post again once I verified the details of the hosting server.

Thanks again for your quick response. :)

Comment: I have resolved the problem, I was missing the dll for the datavisualization in my bin folder on server.

anyways, thanks a ton for your help and guidance.