# Asp.net - <customErrors mode="Off"/> error when trying to access working webpage

Tags: asp.net, web-config, webserver, custom-errors

I have created an asp.net webpage and have uploaded it onto a webserver. However when I try to view the page remotely, I get errors about the customerror tag in the web.config file. The page works locally with no errors or warnings. Also if I upload the page as a .html file, I can view it fine remotely.
I have seen a lot of other people with this error, but the 'solutions' just say to change the customErrors tag to 'Off', which I have done and does not work, do you know is there an issue with the webserver or what could be the problem here?

**Here is the error page:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Runtime Error
>   Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error >settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being >viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running >on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote >machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file >located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag >should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by >modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  >configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**And here is my web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @jvanrhyn probably found your problem. If not, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830361/custom-error-mode-in-web-config-file

Comment: I got the page working remotely, there are 2 web.config files, I was changing the wrong one in the 'account' folder. I should have been changing the one in the project root directory but stupidly didn't see it. jvanrhyn is also right about the one <system.web> tag, thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should only have one `<system.web>` in your `Web.Config Configuration File`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the "Off" is case sensitive, as i just discovered after 20 minutes of trying to solve the same problem

Answer (score 0):

None of those solution work for me but i have this in my web.config

```
<log4net debug="true">
```

either remove all those or go and read errors logs in your application folder\logs

Answer (score -2):

For example in my case I accidentaly changed role of some users to incorrect, and my application got error during starting (NullReferenceException). When I fixed it - the app starts fine.

Answer (score -3):

Sometime in the future
Comment out the following code in web.config

```
 <!--<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>-->
```

update the  to the following code.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full"/>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Why would you suggest changing the .NET framework version or the authentication mode? What do those have to do with solving the issue?