# My browser does not show asp.net errors

Tags: asp.net

I need your help.

When something went wrong in my asp.net code it just returns this message *"Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500"* and it does not give me the specific error, so please could anybody tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Is anything recorded in the event log?

Comment: Is this browser you are accessing your application on running locally on your server or on a client machine?

Comment: Check the web.config file on your server and look for CustomErrors tag. There should be an entry to redirect to a page with the message you are getting. Change the mode to off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check you `web.config` file. And see the `customeError` tag use the blow setting

```
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Here is the more detail about [customeError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx)
You can refer the similar question on SO
[Asp.net - <customErrors mode="Off"/> error when trying to access working webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363941/asp-net-customerrors-mode-off-error-when-trying-to-access-working-webpage)

### Edit -1

More detail about custom error
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2345/Custom-Errors-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

there may be some thing wrong in your code which server not recognized are may be spelling error in your code.
I face this problem in query when i uses join and given wrong return value
For Eg:

```
select tia.*,aht.tutor_uid,ucm.name,ucm.contactdetail from tutor_invoice_against_contract as tia
        left join tutor_billing_against_contract as tba on tba.tbill_id = tia.tbill_id
                     left join ad_hoc_teacher_master as aht on aht.contract_id = tia.contract_id
                    where tia.tin_id = '".$id."'
```

when i uses ath in place of aht its giving this