# n application error occurred on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webserver

After uploading an asp.net mvc application to web server, now getting error msg from exception screen.

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This
> < customErrors > tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

The same application we have been using on other server and it's working fine.

We have checked all of `web.config` with old versions. Everything is correct also it's working on other server.

On error we want to just return same view with error label set with msg as we provided, but we are getting custom error page -showing runtime error ...server error / application.

Also we did not wanted to redirect to custom error page, so we maintained CustomErrorMode ="Off" which was from long time we were using.

Comment: Can you try "To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"." and get detailed error description?

Comment: CustomErrorMode is already set to "Off" there

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363941/asp-net-customerrors-mode-off-error-when-trying-to-access-working-webpage and see if it works?

Comment: Are you getting an issue accessing the web site or can you please add your error msg

Comment: Yes....i am able to access website...but if my login credentials are wrong ...it is giving above error. If i am using correct credential everything in the website working fine

Comment: Check the connection to the database if you have any, also consider folder permission, and asp net app pool

Comment: if we upload same project to other server it is working without error.Issue is only with   this server.Even we tried reverting application to previous working version ....still it is giving same error for old version also.so if it is regarding server.what are the possibilities to check?

Comment: @SagarSonawane any luck, did you fixed it?  I am facing the exact same issue. Solution working fine in one but new server is giving headaches.